# Which countries protested against the Anschluss?

Tags: nazi-germany, austria

In the military history museum in Vienna, one of commentaries said only a few countries protested against Nazi Germany's 1938 annexation of Austria, which the German propaganda apparatus called the *[Anschluss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss)*. Protesting countries included China, Mexico and a few other countries I cannot remember. I tried to google this and found nothing about the Chinese protest and sources claiming Mexico was the only country which protested. Does anyone has a source verifying this?

Comment: What is the anschluss?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Ha ha! Too much wine at dinner tonight perhaps. ;-) I think it is fair to say that anyone who words a coherent question on the *Anschluss*, as here, can be presumed to know what event the term is referring to.

Comment: No, not irony, but if we are to serve as a reference Q&A site, then it behooves us to define foreign terms or terms that are particular to a question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - "Anschluss" isn't a "foreign term". Like "blitzkrieg", it's a borrowed technical term, used in its original form untranslated in English. It also denotes a widely known historical event and is not in **need** of definition on a site such as this, where people presumably know at least 101 level of history of WWII.

Comment: Really, everybody, isn't argumentation in the comment section more work than a simple edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by protest. Mexico was apparently the only country that protested officially to the League of Nations. The Soviet Union condemned the annexation of Austria, of course, as did the Spanish Republic, and (surprisingly) the Vatican.

Comment: The Vatican protest isn't all that surprising. Austria was a majority Catholic nation being taken over by a majority Protestant one.

Comment: A reference would be nice to confirm your confirmation.

Comment: @TenthJustice Cult of personality was more prominent than protestantism for most of 1938's Germany... which also makes it unsurprising that Vatican protests.

Answer (score 7):

> [image]
>   https://www.scoopnest.com/user/intlspectator/873260921212293120

HISTORY: Mexico was the only country in the world to protest Germany's annexation of Austria in 1938 https://t.co/OKb8R6COmQ

"Mexikoplatz (Mexico Square) is a square in the Austrian capital Vienna. It is located in the city's 2nd district, Leopoldstadt, near the banks of the Danube, on the southwestern end of the Reichsbrücke (Empire Bridge), which links Leopoldstadt with Donaustadt, the 22nd district of Vienna."

This plaza was created to honor Mexico and in the middle you will find a monument that thanks Mexico for being the only country in the world that protested the annexation by Germany.